# Python index a numpy array using a variable

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable of an index location as a list, for example, [1,2,3].

I want to select that index from a multidimensional array using this variable. So something like:

```
A = np.array([[0,1],[2,2]])
location = [1,1]
print(A[location])
```

I want that to give me 2, the same that this would:

```
print(A[1,1])
```

But I only have my index in a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: print(A[location[0], location[1]])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to be anti-climactic, but just use a tuple:

```
>>> A[tuple(location)]
2
```

(or just set `location = (1,1)`). A list as indices has special behavior where the matrix is indexed for each element separately and results are concatenated. One specific consequence is that you can have more elements than dimensions which is often surprising as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html).

```py
A = np.array([[0,1],[2,2]])
location = [1,1]
print(np.take(A, location))
```